# Reading a CSV file with quotation and backslashes not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a **CSV file** containing the following lines into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
103028,"Kinokompaniya \"Ego Production\"",[ru],,K5251,K5251,ef6ba1a20ed58265766c35d9e2823f17
60985,"Studio \"Orlenok\", Central Television USSR",[ru],,S3645,S3645,909356683cb8bb5f9872a7f34242b81f
159429,TBWA\CHIAT\DAY,[us],,T123,T1232,e59c9a8f96296cf1418fd92777a5f543
82924,"\"I, of the Craft...\"",[us],,I1326,I1326,3e798b706075164fb6b21cbf20e472d2
130274,"Producentska grupa \"Most\", Zagreb",,,P6325,,1e9cf3da625add311321a8cab69458df
```

However, I am experiencing problems regarding the quotation of the strings and the backslashes.

I have tried adding the `quotechar='"'` and `escapechar='\\'` arguments to the `read_csv` function call. However, in this case the back slashes from `TBWA\CHIAT\DAY` were removed, which is not desired.

Here you can see the output of the whole DataFrame for this case, which would be correct with the exception of line with index 2.

```
       id                                       name country_code  imdb_id name_pcode_nf name_pcode_sf                            md5sum
0  103028             Kinokompaniya "Ego Production"         [ru]      NaN         K5251         K5251  ef6ba1a20ed58265766c35d9e2823f17
1   60985  Studio "Orlenok", Central Television USSR         [ru]      NaN         S3645         S3645  909356683cb8bb5f9872a7f34242b81f
2  159429                               TBWACHIATDAY         [us]      NaN          T123         T1232  e59c9a8f96296cf1418fd92777a5f543
3   82924                       "I, of the Craft..."         [us]      NaN         I1326         I1326  3e798b706075164fb6b21cbf20e472d2
4  130274          Producentska grupa "Most", Zagreb          NaN      NaN         P6325           NaN  1e9cf3da625add311321a8cab69458df
```

Without adding these two arguments, I get the error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 2, saw 8

This is my current code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''103028,"Kinokompaniya \\"Ego Production\\"",[ru],,K5251,K5251,ef6ba1a20ed58265766c35d9e2823f17
60985,"Studio \\"Orlenok\\", Central Television USSR",[ru],,S3645,S3645,909356683cb8bb5f9872a7f34242b81f
159429,TBWA\CHIAT\DAY,[us],,T123,T1232,e59c9a8f96296cf1418fd92777a5f543
82924,"\\"I, of the Craft...\\"",[us],,I1326,I1326,3e798b706075164fb6b21cbf20e472d2
130274,"Producentska grupa \\"Most\\", Zagreb",,,P6325,,1e9cf3da625add311321a8cab69458df
'''

print(data)
```

How can I ensure that all lines are correctly read into the DataFrame?

Comment: *Expected 7 fields in line 2, saw 8* - this error is justified as you actually have different number of fields in different lines, it's not a quoting problem

Comment: You have different number of escape characters in different lines of your data, `\\ ` and `\ `.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code now so that it matches the CSV content specified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is the [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2) standard. Section 2, paragraph 7 states that

```
 7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.  For example:

       "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```

In other words, if the field contains nested double-quotes, the double-quotes must be escaped by another preceding double quote.

The declaration of your `data` variable should look something like this:

```py
data = '''103028,"Kinokompaniya ""Ego Production""",[ru],,K5251,K5251,ef6ba1a20ed58265766c35d9e2823f17
60985,"Studio ""Orlenok"", Central Television USSR",[ru],,S3645,S3645,909356683cb8bb5f9872a7f34242b81f
159429,TBWA"CHIAT"DAY,[us],,T123,T1232,e59c9a8f96296cf1418fd92777a5f543
82924,"""I, of the Craft...""",[us],,I1326,I1326,3e798b706075164fb6b21cbf20e472d2
130274,"Producentska grupa ""Most"", Zagreb",,,P6325,,1e9cf3da625add311321a8cab69458df
'''
```

Consider also specifying the field separator with the `sep` keyword argument (it's always safer this way).

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',', header=None, names=['id', 'name', 'country_code', 'imdb_id', 'name_pcode_nf', 'name_pcode_sf', 'md5sum'])
```

Comment: Does it work as you intended?

Comment: I first tried to replace \" with "" using the "sed" command for performance reasons, but I experienced further issues with some lines in the CSV file.

I was able to resolve the issue in the end by importing the CSV file first into a PostgresSQL DB and then re-exporting it as CSV file with the psql CLI tool. Since I am comparing results between PostgresSQL query execution with Pandas, this was a feasible workaround for me.

Comment: I replaced the backslashes followed by a double-quote in vim, but if you want to do it programmatically you could import the `re` module and use the `sub` method. 
e.g. `data = re.sub(r'\\+"', '""', data)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that escape processing is more aggressive than you want. You could preprocess the data to double-escape backslashes that aren't escaping the quote to get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

data = StringIO('''103028,"Kinokompaniya \\"Ego Production\\"",[ru],,K5251,K5251,ef6ba1a20ed58265766c35d9e2823f17
60985,"Studio \"Orlenok\", Central Television USSR",[ru],,S3645,S3645,909356683cb8bb5f9872a7f34242b81f
159429,TBWA\CHIAT\DAY,[us],,T123,T1232,e59c9a8f96296cf1418fd92777a5f543
82924,"\"I, of the Craft...\"",[us],,I1326,I1326,3e798b706075164fb6b21cbf20e472d2
130274,"Producentska grupa \"Most\", Zagreb",,,P6325,,1e9cf3da625add311321a8cab69458df
''')

# escapes other than `" are double escaped for later csv import
escape_conv_re = re.compile('\\\\(?=[^"])')
escape_converted = StringIO()
escape_converted.writelines(escape_conv_re.sub('\\\\\\\\', line) for line in data)
escape_converted.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(escape_converted,  header=None,
        escapechar='\\', quotechar='"',
        names=['id', 'name', 'country_code', 'imdb_id', 'name_pcode_nf', 'name_pcode_sf', 'md5sum'])

print(df)
```

Result

```
       id                            name               country_code imdb_id name_pcode_nf name_pcode_sf                            md5sum
0  103028  Kinokompaniya "Ego Production"                       [ru]     NaN         K5251         K5251  ef6ba1a20ed58265766c35d9e2823f17
1   60985                 Studio Orlenok"   Central Television USSR"    [ru]           NaN         S3645                             S3645
2  159429                  TBWA\CHIAT\DAY                       [us]     NaN          T123         T1232  e59c9a8f96296cf1418fd92777a5f543
3   82924                               I          of the Craft...""    [us]           NaN         I1326                             I1326
4  130274        Producentska grupa Most"                    Zagreb"     NaN           NaN         P6325                               NaN
```

Since both python and re.sub process the backslash character, you really have to hammer on that thing to stick. `'\\\\\\\\'` ends up being two backslashes on replacement.